# angularjs provider $get populates only one times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
angular.module("app",[]);

angular.module("app").provider("settings",function(){
    this.$get = function(){
        alert("get populated")
        return "hops";
    }
});

angular.module("app").directive("paragraph", function(settings){
    return {
      template: "<p>ok</p>",
      link:function(){
            console.log(settings)
      }
  }
})
```

And I applied my directives like this:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <paragraph></paragraph>
    <paragraph></paragraph>
    <paragraph></paragraph>
</div>
```

But used **`<paragraph>`** directive 3 times but alert works 1 times.

Comment: Because `provider`, `service`, `factory`, `constant`, `value` are singleton in nature, [read docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That is correct.
The provider and other sugar syntax like services , factories are all singletons by default.

1. The provider $get method gets called only when injected. During injection It calls
   the $get function and returns the object/string as per the
   implementation
2. Every subsequent injection, $get function is not called at all. but instead returns the same reference object/string returned
       during the first instance

This is how singleton is implemented in Angularjs.

Answer (score 1):

Providers only interact during the configuration phase. When the application is already running, your "settings" doesn't execute $get, rather, it is equal to "hops". See the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)